# Modify sound volume per application

Tags: fedora, audio, alsa, pulseaudio, mate-desktop

In Fedora 12 + Gnome 2 I used to be able to modify the volume of each application seperately. Now, I'm on Fedora 20 + MATE 1.6.2, and this option is gone.

If I click `Notification Area > Sound > Preferences` or `System > Control Centre > MATE Volume Control`, a window opens that shows Master volume and other stuff like Headphones, Speaker, ACM etc., but I can't control each application's volume settings from here.

Is there any way how to achieve this? I'm in particular interested in dimming Firefox sounds quite, but only sometimes, and sometimes it's other applications, too.

Comment: Maybe in 1.6 that panel wasn't available? At least on Ubuntu MATE (MATE 1.8.1) I can see it: https://i.imgur.com/1JfdfmP.png

Comment: @diffycat Yep, seems right, thanks a lot for pointing out, I didn't notice that 1.8.1's been released. I suppose that questions solved by upgrading to a newer version are considered off-topic, right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved by upgrading to the latest version.